# Deleting a parent node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xml-dml

I have have the following xml fragment in a column in SQL Server

```
<ul>
   <li><a id="cat" href="cat.html">Cat</a></li>
   <li><a id="dog" href="dog.html">Dog</a></li>
```

I want to delete the `<li>` tag that has an `<a>` tag with `id="cat"`

```
    DECLARE @id varchar(40) =  'cat'

    UPDATE  dbo.Pref
    SET     xmlPref.modify('delete /ul/li/a[@id=sql:variable("@id")]')
    WHERE   pref    = 1
```

Does not quite work as it  leaves `<li>` around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the "a" element in the path of expression and add it to the condition

```
DECLARE @id varchar(40) =  'cat'

UPDATE dbo.Pref
SET xmlPref.modify('delete //ul/li[a/@id=sql:variable("@id")]')
WHERE pref = 1
```

See demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/652b0/1)

Answer (score -1):

what about using replace built in function within SQL Server

UPDATE  dbo.Pref
    SET     COLUMNNAME = REPLACE('EXPRESSION TO BE SEARCHED FOR','PART OF THE STRING TO BE SEARCHED','THE REPLACEMENT STRING')
    WHERE   .......